# Is something wrong with my Graphics card, or my Windows?

Tags: windows-7

I am wondering if anyone knows why all my games are crashing and Windows seems to have dots all over the taskbar and videos I'm watching?

I7-4770k 3.5
Nvidia GTX-770 (untouched)
16GB RAM
Sabertooth z87

[image]

If you look closely at the taskbar, it has dots all over it and I think this is what causing my games to crash but I have no idea what it is. Please help ive had this problem for 2 weeks now and its really frustrating. :(

**dxdiag: System**

[image]

**dxdiag  Display**

[image]

Comment: What version of the Nvidia drivers do you have installed?  Post your dxdaig log for us.

Comment: have you tuned your graphics card? if so reset the settings to factory defaults. most likely the card is dying, its being worked too hard.

Comment: I gurentiee its not dying even if it it is,  it's not been worked too hard. :/

Comment: download gpu-z (http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) and take a look at the temps. Also run furmark (http://www.ozone3d.net/benchmarks/fur/) and see if stressing your video card will cause it to make these type of distortion, if yes, I would RMA that card. Edit: Before RMAing it, I would spray it with some compress air and clean it out and make sure it's not over heating.

Answer (score 0):

There must be some troubleshooting steps that you could perform.

- Test with another monitor
- Change the cable / Use another cable (DVI-HDMI)
- Update graphic driver
- Check for any static near the graphic card
- clean the graphic slot, where the card sits.
- Tight the cable in their jacks.

Give it a shot to these simple and easy step. You might fix it.

Comment: I dont think that any of these are the problem i have thigten the cables i have cleaned the graphic slut there is no static neat the graphic card any other solutions ?

Comment: Change the cable, try with another monitor. That will give you where is the issue. Let me know.

Comment: Can i try with hdmi cable to a tv ?

Comment: Soo, i tried to take the vga out and launch bf4 via hdmi.

Comment: The game launched but everything was flickering and all that and after a breef 50 seks the game crashed.

Comment: What if you take your graphic card out and use the built-in mobo's one. You might know what's wrong then.